# how to fix if-else problem in calling functions in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement, readfile

```
if file is not None:
        content = file.readlines()
        if 'I'  and 'J' in content:
            display_oval()
        else:
            display_polygon()
```

in this case,suppose i opened a file containing I&J . i expect to call `display_oval()` but it calls `display_polygon()`. when i opened file not containing I&J,`display_polygon()` calls as expected.
when i replaced `'I' and 'J'`with `'I' or 'J'`,when i opened a file containing I&J,`display_oval()` works fine. But when i opened file not containing I&J, nothing works.
I want to call `display_oval()`if file contains I&J and `display_polygon()`otherwise. how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of intersecting issues with your code.

Thie first issue is that `'I' and 'J' in content` gets grouped as `('I') and ('J' in content)`, which is surely not what you intend. A string like `'I' is always truthy, so testing in that way is not useful. You probably mean` 'I' in content and 'J' in content`.

But that's not enough to fix your code (it makes *fewer* inputs match, not more). The condition will still not work right because your `content` is a list of strings, all but the last of which will be newline terminated. When done on a list, the `in` operator expects exact matches, not substring matches as `in` does when both arguments are strings.

I'm not exactly sure what fix would be best for that second issue. It depends on the logic of your program, and the contents of your file. If you want to test if `I` and `J` show up as individual lines in the file (each separately, on a line with no other characters), you might want to test for `'I\n' in content and 'J\n' in content` using the same `content` you're using now. On the other hand, if you want to check for a capital `I` and `J` characters anywhere in the text of the file, without regard to lines, then you probably need to change `content` instead of changing the matching logic. Use `content = file.read()` to read the whole file into a single string, rather than a list of strings. Then `'I' in content` will do a substring search.

Comment: okay. my file consist of lines and each line consist of strings.       content = file.readlines()
        for line in content:
            for i in line:
                if i == 'I' and 'J':
                    display_oval()
                else:
                    display_polygon() .i rewrite the code as this. But no change in result. Although i want to use readlines() for read file

Comment: `i == 'I' and 'J'` has the same issue I describe in my answer, the `and` operator doesn't distribute the equals like you seem to expect. From your description, it's unclear what you want to be checking for. Do you want to check if both letters are in the same line? Or both letters are in some line, somewhere in the file, but it doesn't need to be the same line. If you want to be searching for those characters anywhere in the file, using `read()` is a lot better than `readlines()`. You can get the results of the latter from the results of the former by calling `splitlines()` on the big string.